# Closed set which does not have open subsets

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I wonder if there is an example of a set $A$ that is closed and that does not contain any nonempty open set.

Comment: Take a single point for example.

Comment: since single point have no limit point , it is closed set??

Comment: A single point is its own and only limit point. A set with a single point does only have the constant sequence which converges to the only point present. So it contains all its limit points, hence is closed.

Comment: You should specify if you're talking about $A$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n,$ a metric space, a topological space etc...

Comment: A as a subset of a metric space

Comment: I will just point out that *not containing a non-empty open set* is equivalent to *having empty interior*. Such sets are also called *co-dense* (see, for example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/116773#116788)) and less frequently boundary set or border set (probably influenced by Polish authors - it's called [Zbiór brzegowy](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zbi%C3%B3r_brzegowy) in Polish).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of such a set with infinitely many elements:

The [set of integers in $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270822/) is closed, and any nonempty subset of integers is closed as well.

Answer (score 2):

In any Hausdorff space, any finite set is closed.

So in any connected Hausdorff space a singleton does contain any non-empty open set.

(I mentioned connectedness as then the singleton cannot be open since it is already closed.)

Answer (score 1):

The empty set is closed and does not contain any nonempty open set. Probably you meant to ask for a **nonempty** closed set which does not contain any nonempty open set. The following theorem answers this question in a general topological space X.

**Theorem.** If in the space $X$ there is a closed set which is not open, then there is a nonempty closed set which does not contain any nonempty open set.

**Proof.** If there is a closed set which is not open, then its complement, call it $U,$ is an open set which is not closed. Of course $U\ne\emptyset,$ since $\emptyset$ is closed. Assuming the axiom of choice, we can extend $\{U\}$ to a maximal collection $\mathcal U$ of pairwise disjoint nonempty open sets. Then the set $A=X\setminus\bigcup\mathcal U$ is a closed set which does not contain any nonempty open set. I claim that $A\ne\emptyset.$

If we had $A=\emptyset,$ it would follow that $\bigcup\mathcal U=X$ and that $\bigcup(\mathcal U\setminus\{U\})=X\setminus U,$ so that $X\setminus U$ would be an open set, contradicting the fact that $U$ is not closed.